# How to add a font awesome icon into input text ::after with j query?

Tags: jquery, web

I have a sign up form like this image:

[image: Click to see that]

After I use jQuery code to check valid email, and that code:

```
function isEmail(email) {
            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
            return regex.test(email);
        }
```

I want to insert a font awesome icon in after my email input form (check icon if true and cross icon if false), like this image:

[image]

So how can I do that with jQuery and I want to set color for this icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `:before` and `:after` does not work for input, you have to set this for the input container.

Try this approach to see if it can help:

**HTLM:**

```
<div class="container">
<h3>Enter valid email</h3>
<div class="input-container" id="email-container">
  <input type="text" required placeholder="you@example.com" id="email" />
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.input-container{
  position:relative;
  height:32px;
}
.input-container input{
  width:100%;
  padding:8px;
}
#email-container:before,
#email-container:after{
  position:absolute;
  right:10px;
  top:10px;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  z-index:1;
  display:none;
}
#email-container:before{
   content:'\f00c';
   color: green;
 }
#email-container:after{
   content:'\f00d';
   color: red
}
.valid-email:before{
  display:block !important;
}
.invalid-email:after{
  display:block !important;
}
.valid{
  border:1px solid green;
}
.invalid{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    $('#email').bind({
    blur: function(){
        if($(this).val() != ''){
        if(isEmail($(this).val())){
            $('#email-container').removeClass('invalid-email').addClass('valid-email');
          $(this).removeClass('invalid');
          $(this).addClass('valid');
        }else{
            $('#email-container').removeClass('valid-email').addClass('invalid-email');
          $(this).removeClass('valid');
          $(this).addClass('invalid');
        }
      }
    }
  });
});

function isEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}
```

See this solution in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/pkm05tax/

Comment: It seems font awesome doesn't support :after stat because i can't add an icon after my input :(

Comment: @KhangHoàngNgô Yeah so use it like the above solution. See it in action https://jsfiddle.net/pkm05tax/

Comment: Do you play fb ? Can i add friend with you ? I have a lot of problems in my web road :v, so can you help me ?

Comment: oops ! I have a problem with your code. I have added a before font awesome icon in input text (email icon), so if i use your code ,my "added icon" will be replaced, what can i do, help me pls ?

Comment: @KhangHoàngNgô yes i use Facebook: fb.me/ssjuma

Answer (score 0):

```js
function isEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}

$('.email').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var emailAddress = $(this).find('input[type=text]').val();
  if (isEmail(emailAddress)) {
   $(this).find('input[type=text]').addClass('fa-check')
  } else {
   $(this).find('input[type=text]').addClass('fa-times')
  };
});
```

```html
<form class="email">
  <input type="text" class="fa">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: so how can i set color for this icon ?

Comment: @KhangHoàngNgô You can change it with CSS, ie `.fa-check{color: green}` and `.fa-times{color : red}`